# How to use Google maps navigation in android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, navigation

I want to use Navigation just like google maps in real time.
Can we transfer data from google map to my android app in real time?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps app for Android exposes several intents that you can use to launch Google Maps in display, search, navigation, or Street View modes. If you want to embed a map in your app,  refer to the Google Maps Android API Guide on the google maps API site.